# Is there any way to set hardware profiles based on where I am at?

Tags: hardware, screensaver

Like in windows xp you use to be able to create a new hard profile and then you select which one you want before windows boots.

Basically what I want to do is kill the screen saver when I go home, like when I am watching movies and it is not plugged in, so I don't have to move the mouse every 5 mins or so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This guide is half of your solution:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=3550

Basically it has you add an option to your GRUB menu that starts the system at a different runlevel. Then you can modify the scripts for that runlevel which will configure the system however you want. However, the second half of the guide only covers modifying xsetup and your network interfaces.

The setting you're looking for is in Power Management. We can use `gconf-editor` to find the name of the setting, in this case `/apps/gnome-power-manager/timeout/sleep_display_battery`. A setting of 0 will disable the screen shut-off, otherwise it is the number of seconds until shut-off. To change this setting using a runlevel script or the command-line, you can run:

```
$ gconftool-2 --set "/apps/gnome-power-manager/timeout/sleep_display_battery" --type integer 0
```

If you're having trouble putting that command and the runlevel guide together, please comment on this and I will try and assist further.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can alter the screen time out in the batter profiles. where i presume you are plugged in to AC power. Or add an inhibitor applet to your panel. when you click on it, the screen will not turn off! =)